# Least action principle for Dirac monopole

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, variational-principle, magnetic-monopoles

I want to find the Lorentz force formula for the magnetic charge through the principle of least action. The magnetic charge is introduced by Dirac adding inside the electromagnetic tensor a tensor $G^{\mu \nu}$ such that $\partial_\mu G^{\mu \nu}=j^\nu$ and $$F_{\mu \nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu + * G_{\mu \nu}.$$
Where $*$ stands for the Hodge dual and $$j^\nu = g \int \delta^{(4)}(x-x(\tau)) \frac {dx^\nu}{d \lambda} d\lambda.$$

The action which describes the magnetic charge motion is
$$
I = - \frac{1}{4} \int F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu}d^4x  - m \int \frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{dx_\mu}{d\lambda} d \lambda.
$$
Varying this action with respect to $x^\mu$ we should find the Lorentz force for the monopole
$$
m \frac{dp^\mu}{d\lambda} = g \frac{dx_\mu}{d \lambda}*F^{\mu \nu}.
$$

I'm stuck with the calculations for the first part
\begin{align}
&\delta_{x^\mu} I =\\ 
&=- \frac{1}{4} \int2 F^{\mu \nu}\delta_{x^\mu}F_{\mu \nu}d^4x \\
&=- \frac{1}{2}\int F^{\mu \nu}\boxed{\partial_\mu * G_{\mu \nu}} \delta_{x^\mu} d^4x.
\end{align}

How I compute $\partial_\mu * G_{\mu \nu}$?  Can I move the Hodge operator to $F^{\mu \nu}$? How? I also tried to compute Euler-Lagrange equations but at some point I get the same problem...

Comment: $^*G_{\mu\nu}$ is simply $\sim \epsilon_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}G^{\alpha\beta}$.

Comment: So is this correct following your answer?

$$
F_{\mu \nu} \partial^\nu (\ast G^{\mu \nu})\\
= F_{\mu \nu} \partial^\nu (\varepsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} G_{\rho \sigma})\\
= \varepsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} F_{\mu \nu} \partial^\nu G_{\rho \sigma}\\
= \ast F^{\rho \sigma} \partial^\rho G_{\rho \sigma}\\
= \ast F^{\rho \sigma} j_\sigma
$$

Comment: Yes, it seems correct. I naively do not see tricky moments in these transformations. Your theory seems very similar to Cabibo-Ferrari model, where the additional 4-potential added to the definition of EM-tensor. This model is well-known and it is possible to find detailed derivations of equations of motion, I assume